# How to build a spring controller with datas from two tables

Tags: java, sql, spring, postgresql, controller

The problem is as following: I have to make a spring controller with a parameter ("/getDocumentInfo?uniqueDocNo=100)", but I can't get the all the datas because I can't make a proper join between them.

First table, *Document*, contains datas about a document and the table *Email* contains data about who was sent the document and what was in the email.
The first table contains the parameter uniqueDocNo and another variable that I do need, but the second table contains uniqueDocNo only as a part of a concatenated field. I tried to make some mappings myself but I'm not sure I understood how I can get all my datas and put them in the controller only with one parameter(uniqueDocNo) or even if it is possible.

Tables: *Document*(**uniqueDocNo**, seenYN, docName, crDate), 
*Email*(**emailNo**, emailDate, emailTo, emailSubject, *internNo*).
PK are with bold and in italic is the field that is concatenated. For example: uniqueDocNo = 100, internNo = 100_other_numbers_i_dont_need.

I expect to have a mapper or something that can the datas from both tables for the uniqueDocNo, more precisely: uniqueDocNo, seenYN(from the first table) and all the datas from the second table according to the the uniqueDocNo.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you add some code to your question ?, Are you using JdbcTemplate ?

Comment: Not sure if I understood fully, but can the native SQL be considered for the finder methods where the join on second table is based on t1.colx  = t2.substring(coly..) logic